# Pandas Groupby ValueError: The truth value of a DataFrame is ambiguous

Tags: python, pandas

I create a new DataFrame from a SQL query using Pandas's read_sql_query function.

When iterating through the DataFrame, there are several dimension columns we do a groupby function, and it often works. However, for certain columns it will not and instead I get an error. The error is:

```
ValueError: The truth value of a DataFrame is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

In my attempt to replicate the issue, I created a dict and turned it into a DataFrame. This new DataFrame also has values (strings) that were unique. The groupby function works as it should. It appears that maybe if the DataFrame was created from a sql query, it has issues with groupby? Because I cannot reproduce      the issue outside of a query to our database (PostgreSQL) I cannot past anything run-able here. Below is the code I use to create the DataFrame from SQL

```
cur = conn.cursor()
query ="""SELECT * from table1""" 
df = pd.read_sql_query(query, conn)
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
df = df.set_index(pd.DatetimeIndex(df['date']))
```

I don't think there's anything crazy with how I'm doing the above.

Trackback:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-410-83c5166962e7> in <module>()
      5 
      6 df1 = df.drop(['client_name', 'class_type', 'message', 'from_name', 'from_id'], axis=1)
----> 7 df1.groupby('post_id').sum()
      8 
      9 #             current_data = current_data.set_index(dim)

/Users/Dev/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.pyc in groupby(self, by, axis, level, as_index, sort, group_keys, squeeze)
   3157         axis = self._get_axis_number(axis)
   3158         return groupby(self, by=by, axis=axis, level=level, as_index=as_index,
-> 3159                        sort=sort, group_keys=group_keys, squeeze=squeeze)
   3160 
   3161     def asfreq(self, freq, method=None, how=None, normalize=False):

/Users/Dev/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/groupby.pyc in groupby(obj, by, **kwds)
   1197         raise TypeError('invalid type: %s' % type(obj))
   1198 
-> 1199     return klass(obj, by, **kwds)
   1200 
   1201 

/Users/Dev/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/groupby.pyc in __init__(self, obj, keys, axis, level, grouper, exclusions, selection, as_index, sort, group_keys, squeeze)
    386         if grouper is None:
    387             grouper, exclusions, obj = _get_grouper(obj, keys, axis=axis,
--> 388                                                     level=level, sort=sort)
    389 
    390         self.obj = obj

/Users/Dev/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/groupby.pyc in _get_grouper(obj, key, axis, level, sort)
   2152             in_axis, name = False, None
   2153 
-> 2154         if is_categorical_dtype(gpr) and len(gpr) != len(obj):
   2155             raise ValueError("Categorical dtype grouper must have len(grouper) == len(data)")
   2156 

/Users/Dev/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.pyc in __nonzero__(self)
    712         raise ValueError("The truth value of a {0} is ambiguous. "
    713                          "Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()."
--> 714                          .format(self.__class__.__name__))
    715 
    716     __bool__ = __nonzero__

ValueError: The truth value of a DataFrame is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

Comment: Can you post the full trace back?

Comment: Can you post the results of df1.info()?

Comment: Why don't you just do `df = df.set_index('date')`? What you've tried to do is pass DateTimeIndex as the keys which is probably why it borked, you didn't need to construct a DateTimeIndex, the dtype is already datetime, and you didn't need to construct the index, just pass the name. See the [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html#pandas.DataFrame.set_index)

Comment: Here's what I get for df1.info():   
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
DatetimeIndex: 102 entries, 2015-07-14 00:30:01 to 2015-09-14 18:22:46
Columns: 257 entries, post_id to week
dtypes: datetime64[ns](6), float64(49), int64(32), object(170)
memory usage: 205.6+ KB